# How can I get react code to display with the proper syntax highlighting in Sublime?

Tags: reactjs, sublimetext3

The obvious answer to this question seems to be that I should install the Babel package. However, I'm unable to find the Babel package via Package Control.

Is there a way that I can make package control find it or install in manually? 
Any idea, why isn't package control finding it?

Maybe I don't know how to use Package Control properly?

Note:
I'm using the most recent update of Sublime 3 (Build 3126).

Comment: Do you have a link to the package in question? The first hit I get is the following but it seems to be in Package Control just fine: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Babel

Comment: Am I supposed to paste that URL into Package Control somehow?

Comment: If you have Package Control installed, you should be able to select `Preferences > Package Control` from the menu, then the `Install Package` command, and select `Babel` from the list to install it.

Comment: I think I just stumbled upon part of the answer. I went to Package Control: Install Package ...then found the Babel package and installed it. Now I just have to figure out how to get sublime to always use it on .js files in the project.

Comment: @OdatNurd I think I figured that out as you were commenting. Thanks! ..but now I'm still trying to figure out the next part.

Comment: For that, while you have a JavaScript file open, select `View > Syntax > Open all with current extension as...` from the menu and select Babel from the list.

Comment: @OdatNurd Thanks! Question: Do you think that will mess me up if I look at non-react .js files in other projects?
Also, very helpful info -- please answer the question!

Comment: @pixelfairy You can change the syntax for a buffer at any time using the `Command Palette`, e.g. press `Ctrl+Shift+P` and type `Set Syntax: JavaScript` due to ST's fuzzy letter matching just typing `SSJS` will get you there (or close enough). Use the `Open all with current extension` feature to set what you want the default syntax for the file extension to be and then use the `Command Palette` to change it when required. I think you would benefit from doing a Sublime Text tutorial, do a web search you'll find lots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package that you want is probably the [Babel](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Babel) package, which is in package control already. In order to install it, you can open the command palette and select the `Package Control: Install Package` command, then select `Babel` from the list of packages that is presented. You can also select `Preferences > Package Control` to open the command palette with the list of commands for package Control displayed (under MacOS, the `Preferences` menu is under `Sublime Text` in the menu).

If this isn't the package that you want to use, and the package is not in Package Control but IS available via GitHub or BitBucket, you can still install the package with Packge Control by selecting `Package Control: Add Repository` from the command palette (same list as above) and providing the repository URL. This will make the package available as an installable package as if it is was natively in Package Control.

As an aside, in general Sublime selects the syntax to use for a file based on its extension, which means that for packages like Babel that provide syntax definitions for file extensions that Sublime already supports (in this case JavaScript), you may need to take extra steps.

In particular if you use a file extension like `js`, Sublime will treat it as JavaScript. You can swap the syntax to a different one by selecting it from the `View > Syntax` menu, clicking on name of the current syntax in the status line (if it's visible) or selecting the appropriate `Set Syntax:` command from the command palette.

This can be a drag if you mostly work with the alternate format file; in this case you can use `View > Syntax > Open all with current extension as...` from the menu while you have a JavaScript file open and select the appropriate syntax to change the default.

This flips your problem around so that you now need to manually select the JavaScript extension, however. Depending on which syntax you use most often this may or may not be a big deal. You can also perform the same step to change the default back.

As an alternate solution to this problem, if you use `sublime-project` files you can use the [Project Specific Syntax Settings](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Project%20Specific%20Syntax%20Settings) package to automatically select the appropriate syntax based on the current needs of your project.

Answer (score 1):

Installing babel on sublime3:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

Then type install and select first option Package control: `Install Package`

Then type `Babel` and select the first option.

It will install babel in few moments.

Edit: The first option package name is `Babel-Snippets` as pointed out in the comments below.

Then select Babel Syntax.

`View > Syntax > Babel > Javascript`